# SQL Server account per-table privileges

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, accounts

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, is it possible for a SQL Server account to be given privileges on a per-table basis within a database? For example, to have read access to all tables but write access to only one of the tables.

I am already familiar with the per-database security settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the GRANT statement, i.e.

> GRANT UPDATE on myTable to
>   myUserorRole

..or if the writing will be done via a stored procedure, grant execute to the proc.

Granting to roles rather than a specific account would be a good idea, then add the role to the account.

Check Books OnLine (BOL) for details.

Comment: That looks promising but I get an error. If I have a table "dbo.MyTable" with user "MyUser" and I try "GRANT UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON dbo.MyTable TO MyUser;" it says "Cannot find the object 'MyTable', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." I have full permissions to the database but I am not an administrator for the db server, could that be a problem?

Comment: Found it, I can right-click on the table, go to properties, and play with permissions in there and it works. Thanks for the help, you got me going in the right direction.